# Maintaing Input Values in Dynamically Generated Fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamically-generated

I have the following JavaScript which generates text-inputs dynamically and inserts them into a div. This code works fine, but if I type text into the field, then click the button to add another field I lose the text I typed in the first field.

I made a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBp4g/3/) - but for some reason it's not working. The same code works fine in my browser though.

Here's the function in question:

```
var optCount = 0;
function addOption(type){
    var cont = document.getElementById('new'+type+'Opts');
    cont.innerHTML = cont.innerHTML + "<span style='display:block;' id='opt" + optCount + "'><input type='text' style='width:80%;' /><a href='#' style='color:red; text-decoration:none; font-size:.6em;' onclick=\"return delOpt('opt" + optCount + "');\">[x]</a><br /></span>";
    optCount++;
    return false;
}
```

How can I maintain the values of the existing fields when adding additional fields?

Comment: It's not finding `addOption`, since that's only added at document ready, and is being referenced when the dom loads.  Just change the jsfiddle option in the top left corner to "No wrap - in <head>", and your code will execute. http://jsfiddle.net/PBp4g/4/  (Note, this doesn't fix your problem, it just fixes your fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace the entire contents of the div every time.  Instead, just create the new option and append it.

```
var cont = document.getElementById("new"+type+"Opts");
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'block';
span.id = "opt" + optCount;
span.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='width80' /><a href='#' class='dellink' onclick=\"return delOpt('opt" + optCount + "');\">[x]</a><br />";
optCount++;
cont.appendChild(span);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PBp4g/5/